# Creating 2D grid or mesh inside a cross section profile

Tags: r, intersection, mesh, profile

2D grid in R?
I have a river cross section with its profile in terms of Y versus Z.
and would like to create a mesh in between the channel bed and a depth of water. Either of triangular and rectangular meshes are OK. The grid can be 0.01 x 0.01 m apart or any other. My target is to get the Y and Z coordinates of each mesh. 
Thanks in advance for your kind cooperation

profile data

```
Y=c(-30,-2,0,8,20,31) 
Z=c(30,10,2,9,30,39)
```

Comment: Welcome! Your question is very broad. Please [edit] your question and try to add some details and relevant code you already tried.

Comment: hi, i could do it myself. maybe you can check it, please @ventiseis

Answer (score 0):

- Since I posted this, i was working on it, finally I could develope the code
- anyone can use it. 
  -here is the cross section profile

`Y=c(-30,-2,0,8,20,31)`

`Z=c(30,10,2,9,30,39)`

-To create a grid of points inside the cross section
      - select y and z grid spacing

`ygrid= 50 #cm`
`zgrid= 20 #cm`

`Ym = seq(min(Y),max(Y),ygrid/100`  #y grid coord along the section

## create an interpolation fucntion

```
f_z=approxfun(Y,Z) 
Zm = f_z(Ym)             #interpolated z coordinates of the section perimeter
```

`plot(Ym, Zm,type="b")`

## the depth for which we have the observed surf. velocity or Q discharge

```
Depth_study = 6.05
```

## create different depths from the section bed to the study depth

```
Depthm = seq(Z_bed,Depth_study,zgrid/100) # different water depths w/r to 0,0 point
```

## now for different depth, take out the indices which Zm<=Depthm

`list_points_mesh<-vector(("list"),length =length(Depthm))`

`Y_mesh<-vector(("list"),length =length(Depthm))`

`Z_mesh<-vector(("list"),length =length(Depthm))`

```
for (j in 1:length(Depthm)) {
  list_points_mesh[[j]] = which(Zm<=Depthm[j])  #gives indice of all the points which are below Depthm elevation
  Y_mesh[[j]] = Ym[list_points_mesh[[j]]]  #now we create pair of points using the indices
  Z_mesh[[j]]= rep(Depthm[j],length(list_points_mesh[[j]]))
}
```

## since the answer comes in form of a list, we take them out by unlist func.

```
ym=unlist(Y_mesh)   #y coord of the grid points
zm=unlist(Z_mesh)  #z // //    //   //
mesh_coord <- data.frame(ym,zm)  #list of points inside the section
points(ym,zm,pch=".")
```